# MySQL for Oracle DBA

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysqldump, mysql-5.6

I am a newbie to MySQL, but understand Oracle databases well. I need a quick help to understand the architectural differences. Currently I am working on a Windows platform.

1) In Oracle we have to put the database in archive log mode, do we have to do this with MySQL to perform point in time recovery?

2) In Oracle, an instance starts with memory structure SGA. How does it work in MySQL?

3) RMAN is the online backup tool for oracle. MySQL backup for MySQL, is it capable to do point in time recovery?

4) I don't understand logging and database files layout in MySQL In Oracle if i create tablespace  we see a file on the file system with name. How does this work in MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

**Q)** RMAN is the online backup tool for oracle. MySQL backup for MySQL, is it capable to do point in time recovery?

**A)** MySQL use `mysqldump` as online backup tool.

**Q)** In Oracle, an instance starts with memory structure SGA. How does it work in MySQL?

**A)** In MySQL, tuning of the caches similar to Oracle’s buffer cache is done on a per storage engine basis. For the MyISAM engine, the key_buffer can be used to cache index data only, and relies on the underlying operating system to cache data files unlike Oracle’s buffer cache. Because of this difference, while a dedicated Oracle database might allocate 80% of the system’s main memory to the buffer cache, often MySQL’s key buffer does not get set to much over 50% of the database system’s main memory for optimal tuning.

MySQL’s InnoDB storage engine has a more similar cache to Oracle’s buffer cache called innodb_buffer_pool_size and caches both index and data blocks. Like Oracle’s buffer pool, a dedicated MySQL system using only InnoDB tables would do well to set to up 80% of the systems main memory for use in this cache.

**Q)** I don't understand logging and database files layout in MySQL In Oracle if i create tablespace we see a file on the file system with name. How does this work in MySQL?

**A)** Each database managed by the MySQL server has its own database directory. This exists as a subdirectory of the data directory, with the same name as the database it represents. For example, a database `mydb` corresponds to the database directory `DATADIR/mydb`. This representation allows several database-level statements to be almost trivial in their implementation.

**Q)** In Oracle we have to put the database in archive log mode, do we have to do this with MySQL to perform point in time recovery?

**A)**  I found something similar to this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093/best-way-to-archive-live-mysql-database

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. I guess last question was .. In Oracle if we dont put the db in archive log mode .. redo log overwrites itself .. this means we cant do point in time recovery ... IN mysql .. does it log sequentially without overwriting itself ?

Comment: without external tools no.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ahmad's answer let me give you a few links that might be useful.

When it comes to enterprise grade backup, point-in-time recovery, backup schedules etc. use [MEB (MySQL Enterprise Backup)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/4.0/en/).

If you would like to manage a MySQL DB from Oracle Enterprise Manager use this [MySQL Database plugin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-em-plugin/en/).

Answer (score 0):

I addition to Admad answer for 4th question related to Archive log , you can use bin-log in MySQL which will record all the changes in Database and if in case your database get fail , you can use these logs for your database recovery.

Bin logs can be enabled by specifying bin log in conf file of MySQL .